# Xcode watchOS 10.1 SwiftUI animation not working like it used to

Tags: xcode, swiftui, watchos

Ive got a little animation on the first screen on my watchOS app that simply changes some opacity to reveal a checkmark, but in watchOS 10.1 it's not doing what it used to. I can't use the simulator to find out why because I haven't got the watchOS 10.1 simulator. Its just on my physical device I'm not seeing the opacity change anymore. - here is the code that works on watch OS 10

```
func updatCurrentProgress() {
        print("updatCurrentProgress")
        withAnimation(.interpolatingSpring(duration: 1.2, bounce: 0.0, initialVelocity: 0.0).delay(0.5)) {
            currentProgress = tiyowehSession.currentDayGoalComplete
        } completion: {
            if customGoalValue > 0 && UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: "currentDayGoalComplete") < 1.0 && tiyowehSession.currentDayGoalComplete >= 1.0 {
                WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(.notification)
                print("playing .success)")
                goalProgressViewOpasity = 0.0
                goalCompleteTickOpasity = 1.0
                withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 2.0).delay(1.2)) {
                    goalCompleteTickOpasity = 0.0
                    goalProgressViewOpasity = 1.0
                }
            }
            UserDefaults.standard.set(currentProgress, forKey: "currentDayGoalComplete")
        }
    }
```

.

The sound plays correctly

> WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(.notification)

but the opacity dosent change like it used to.
Can cayenne see any issues?
Thanks.